# Error in git push master causing no files in staging area

Tags: git, bitbucket, staging

I searched in stack overflow but I couldn't get working answer. I pushed my huge changes from staging area to repository. An error came in middle. Now when I enter git status or git status -s, it shows that no changes are present but when I go to repository master it doesn't show any commit.

Comment: what error appeared ?

Comment: did you commit first? If you committed; then you probably have a (huge) commit locally that hasn't been pushed...

Comment: Yes, that is the case and error was postbuffer related which I forgot to increase. The main problem is that there were 100s of files for master push . Any technique to diff/recover between remote repository and staging area ?

Comment: your language is confusing... can't you just change your commit then (git commit --amend) and push again?

Comment: No, it didn't helped while I searched the git help manual, it says that pull down a new workspace and replace it with all old workspace files except .git folder. Make a new commit

Answer (score 0):

Git pushes commits, not individual files.

There is a bunch of optimization on this (depending on protocol) but the principle works out the same: git either completely pushes one or more commits, which are then present on the remote, or it fails, so that they are not present on the remote.

In either case, your local repository is *not affected*.  Your commits and your (local) branches are unchanged.  The only thing that does change is that if your push succeeds, your remote-tracking branches for that remote are updated, since your git knows that their git accepted your pushed commits.

If you've committed everything locally before you start your `git push` attempt, `git status` will show nothing to be committed.  If your `git push` fails—whether it's because of a network failure while pushing, or because the remote rejects the push—`git status` will *still* show nothing to be committed.  That's not important!  What matters is retrying the push (if the push should have succeeded), or removing and/or replacing the commit(s) you no longer want to push (if the push should have failed).

To "remove" a commit,<sup>1</sup> you can use `git reset` or `git rebase -i`.  To replace the tip-most commit, you can use `git commit --amend` after using `git add` and/or `git rm` to update files in the staging area.  (Note, by the way, that all the files you recently committed are still in the staging area, they're just the same as they are in the commit you just made, so `git status` says nothing about them.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Commits don't actually go away, at least not immediately, hence the quotes around "removed".  These "removed" commits typically remain available via two reflogs (one for `HEAD` and one for the current branch) for 30 days (though this is all configurable).

The same holds for `git commit --amend`: it just moves the tip-most commit aside and makes a new tip-most commit whose parent is the same as the commit just moved-aside.  The moved-aside commit is in the same reflogs as with using `git reset` or `git rebase -i`.